# How to match strings of the form "exclude=1" using regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to use a regular expression to match strings of the form `exclude=1` where the number should be in the range of 1 to 15.

I've tried: 
`str.match("/exclude\=[1-9]|exclude\=1[0-5]/")`

but it does not work.

Thank you!

Comment: `.match` should accept a regular expression, not a string. If you pass a string containing `/`s, literal `/`s will be matched, which is not what you want here. Use a regex literal instead

Comment: You might shorten it to `\bexclude=(?:[1-9]|1[0-5])\b`

Comment: do you want to extract the part or just to check the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You took a string,

```
str.match("/exclude\=[1-9]|exclude\=1[0-5]/")
          ^                                ^
```

but you need to remove the quotes for a regular expression and take a start and end sign into the expression.

```js
const test = s => s.match(/^exclude=([1-9]|1[0-5])$/);

console.log(['', 'exclude=1', 'exclude=15', 'exclude=153'].map(test));
```